# Formik use debounce on change input

Tags: reactjs, formik, debouncing

I have this simple example using useDebouncedCallback from use-debounce. When i write to input it remains the same with no value. What iam doing wrong?

```
const SignupForm = () => {

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
    },

  });

  const debounced = useDebouncedCallback(
    // function
    (event) => {
      formik.handleChange(event);
    },
    // delay in ms
    1000
  );


  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input
        id="firstName"
        name="firstName"
        type="text"
 
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        onChange={(e) => {
          e.persist();
          debounced(e);
      
        }}
        value={formik.values.firstName}
      />

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is it working without using the `debounced` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you have a controlled component (due to `value={formik.values.firstName}`).

When `formik.handleChange` is called (in an debounced way), `e.target.value` is empty because React keeps the input field in sync with `formik.values.firstName` which remains empty (its initial value is `firstName: ""`).

To make it work, you can use the formik [setFieldValue](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void) and pass the input name and value to the debounced function like this :

```js
const debounced = useDebouncedCallback(
  (field, value) => formik.setFieldValue(field, value),
  1000
);
...
<input
  id="firstName"
  name="firstName"
  type="text"
  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
  onChange={(e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    debounced(name, value);
  }}
  value={formik.values.firstName}
/>
```

Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-soxkfo?file=src/App.js)